# Recursive selection sort (JS)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm writing recursive selection sort in JavaScript.

**Expecting behavior**: I want the function `selectionSort()`to sort values in array in ascending order.

**Problem**: I cannot get out from recursion and I don't know how.

**Error**:

> `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

---

Here is my code:

```js
const findSmallestIndex = ( arr ) => {
    let smallest = arr[0];
    let smallestIndex = 0;
    let arrLen = arr.length;

    for ( let i = 0; i < arrLen; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] < smallest ) {
            smallest = arr[i];
            smallestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return smallestIndex;
};

const selectionSort = ( arr ) => {
    let smallest = arr.splice( findSmallestIndex( arr ), 1 );
    return [smallest].concat( selectionSort( arr ) );
};

let arr = [23, 43, 23423, 66, 5, 57, 78, 0, 1];

console.log( selectionSort(arr) );
```

Comment: *"isn't working"* ***how***? What do you see? What do you expect instead? When you step through the code with the debugger, what about what you're seeing it do don't you understand?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I cannot get out from recursion and I don't know how

Comment: Your recursion does not have a base case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to add the condition for the completion of recursion (so called **Base case**) `if ( !arr.length ) return []`
2. `arr.splice( findSmallestIndex( arr ), 1 )` returns Array and no need in `[smallest]...` - just `smallest.concat( selectionSort( arr ) )`
3. **Improvement**: your code mutates `arr` (noted by [ftor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6445533/ftor)) so we can fix it by adding `let newArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( arr );`

```js
/**
 * Finds smallest element of an aray
 * @param {Array} arr array for searching
 * @return {number} index of the smallest element in array
 */
const findSmallestIndex = ( arr ) => {
    let smallest = arr[0];
    let smallestIndex = 0;
    let arrLen = arr.length;

    for ( let i = 0; i < arrLen; i++ ) {
        if ( arr[i] < smallest ) {
            smallest = arr[i];
            smallestIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return smallestIndex;
};

/**
 * Sorts recursively an array of numbers
 * @param {Array} arr An array of numbers
 * @return {Array} New sorted array
 */
const selectionSort = ( arr ) => {
    if ( !arr.length ) return [];
    let newArray = Array.prototype.slice.call( arr );
    let smallest = arr.splice( findSmallestIndex( arr ), 1 );
    return smallest.concat( selectionSort( arr ) );
};

let arr = [23, 43, 23423, 66, 5, 57, 78, 0, 1];

console.log( selectionSort(arr) );
```

**Featured links and terms**:

1. [Mastering recursive programming](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-recurs/)
2. [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
3. [**Base case**](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~agrawal/spring2010/Lecture13.pdf) - the case for which the solution can be stated non‐recursively
4. [**General (recursive) case**](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~agrawal/spring2010/Lecture13.pdf) - the case for which the solution is expressed in terms of a smaller version of itself

Comment: It is noteworthy that this solution mutates `arr` and for larger arrays will blow the stack and will rather be slow, because each recursive step creates a new array.

Comment: @ftor Thank you. It seems that I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is more performant way of doing it.

```
function selectionSort(arr) {

    var swap = function(x, y) {
        var temp = arr[y];
        arr[y] = arr[x];
        arr[x] = temp;
    }

    var sort = function(start) {
        if (start === arr.length) {
            return arr;
        }

        var min = start;

        for (var i = start + 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] < arr[min]) {
                min = i;
            }
        }

        swap(start, min);

        return sort(start + 1);
    }

    return sort(0);
}

selectionSort([23, 43, 23423, 66, 5, 57, 78, 0, 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectionSort(arr, min){

if(min == arr.length) return arr; 

var temp = arr[min]; 

var low = arr[min] ; 
var lowIdx ; 

for(let i = min + 1 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
        
    if(arr[i] < low){
        low = arr[i] ;  
        lowIdx = i ; 
    }
}

//if there is no elem lesser than 'low' then 'lowIdx' will be undefined
//i.e. array is sorted 
if(lowIdx == undefined ) return arr; 

arr[min] = low ; 
arr[lowIdx] = temp; 

return selectionSort(arr, min+1); 
}
```